# GIT Source Tree Merge Develop Branch into Stage Branch Conflict

Tags: git, merge, conflict

I am using Sourcetree to merge my Develop branch into the Staging Branch. There was a conflict which I resolved. I run Git Status and there is no additional files to add / conflicted. 
My branch now states (stage|MERGING)
Here is where my confusion starts. Do I need to start the merge process all over again since I resolved the conflicts, or is it simply a matter of commit -> then push ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed just need to commit and push at that point.